# Conver a Pandas Dataframe into a Dictionary of Lists, grouping by one column

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have data in this format:

```
term_x       similar_sounding_term

insurance    insurance_policy
insurance    insurance_quote
insurance    car_insurance
car rental   rental cars in Nantucket
car rental   damaged car rental policy
```

I want to transform this dataframe into a dictionary where the key is term_x but the value is a list of all of the values asscoiated in that term, so:

```
insurance : [insurance_policy, insurance_quote, car_insurance, rental cars in Nantucket....]
```

and so forth:

I though the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39078078/converting-a-dataframe-to-dictionary-with-multiple-values) solved my problem but it did not merge the lists under one key like I had hoped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df.groupby('term_x')['similar_sounding_term'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[1690]: 
{'carrental': ['rentalcarsinNantucket', 'damagedcarrentalpolicy'],
 'insurance': ['insurance_policy', 'insurance_quote', 'car_insurance']}
```